# Browser doesn't stop loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I use Windows 7, ASP.NET MVC3 and IIS 7.5. When i debug MVC project, browser opens, loading continues, but page does not open. When i stop debug in Visual Studio, page opens. Please help me..

Comment: are you sure you don't have a breakpoint somewhere?

Comment: i have not breakpoint. im sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found problem's reason myself, I turned off antivirus program, then everything is ok. Thanks